# Testflight Renew loop issue

Tags: ios, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

Sometimes TestFlight show a `RENEW` button instead of `INSTALL` or `UPDATE`, but it works the same as the an updating.

Now it started to looping the `RENEW` button, like there is a `Provisioning Profile` issue, but i refreshed all the profiles in [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) and also in my `Xcode` preferences and `Build Settings`.

[Video about the issue](https://vid.me/1MUV)

Comment: I have the same issue in my TestFlight app. But, here in some devices (out of 7 devices 2 only) after clicking on `RENEW`, the TestFlight app itself got stuck and crashing. I need to release the same build to public, please confirm that this issue will effect release or not.

Answer (score 1):

Usually renew button appears to internal testers after the app is approved for external beta testing by Apple.

If you see the Renew button in other occasions too, try to regenerate your developer certificate (not just the provisioning profile).

Comment: this is an internal testers only version. I am not going to revoke my any of my Certificates, thats not a real solution

Comment: You can always file a radar to apple.

Answer (score 1):

You usually can fix this by rebuilding you binary and send as a new build version number.

I don't know if it's the best solution but it works for me.

Comment: For now, the best "solution" is to regenerate/recompile anything ... but its still a pain in the *$$